# SQL statement with LIKE

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I would like to select all records that have an underscore character in their 11th character,
so i try this:

```
SELECT * FROM "BOM_SUB_LEVEL" where TOP_CODE like '%%%%%%%%%%_%%%'
```

but this doesnt work as expected, can someone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use the "SUBSTRING" function :

```
SELECT * FROM "BOM_SUB_LEVEL" where SUBSTRING(TOP_CODE, 11, 1) = "_"
```

Marc

Comment: +1 you beet me to it marc, I think this is the best (fastest) option.

Comment: +1. This makes way more sense than a whole bunch of single-character wildcards.

Answer (score 11):

For a single character wildcard use `_`. For multiple characters wildcards, use `%`. To escape a "real" appearance of `_`, use `\_` (thanks Bill!).

Try the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM "BOM_SUB_LEVEL" where TOP_CODE like '___________\_%'
```

To further elaborate following Dav's comment, note that '%%%' is exactly the same as '%', since by definition '%' covers multiple characters.

Comment: To elaborate on why this works and your original doesn't, chicane - the `%` wildcard is an "any number of characters" wildcard - so `%` is the same as `%%` is the same as `%%%` and so on because even a single one can match multiple characters.

Comment: @Dav: I wrote my additional text before you posted your comment, no plagiarism intended...

Comment: "?" is not a wildcard for LIKE predicates in Pervasive.

Answer (score 2):

pervasive uses _ to match any single character and \_ to actually match an underscore.

so the select would be:

```
SELECT * FROM "BOM_SUB_LEVEL" where TOP_CODE like '___________\_%'
```

Answer (score 1):

LIKE % can mean any number of characters, use LIKE _ to mean just one. Since you're looking for an underscore, you need to escape it with !.

```
SELECT * FROM BOM_SUB_LEVEL WHERE TOP_CODE LIKE '__________!_%'
```

Comment: I missed the pervasive tag, this answer is for SQL Server

Comment: Pervasive uses backslash, not exclamation mark, to escape wildcards in LIKE patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The % is not a per character wildcard, its a beginning and end of string wild card.

i.e. if I want to find all rows that have "car" in them, I would do this:

Select * from myTable where myCol LIKE '%car%'

If I wanted just the rows that STARTED with car:

Select * from myTable where myCol LIKE 'car%'

and ended with car:

Select * from myTable where myCol LIKE '%car'

Comment: it's any combination, so LIKE "c%r" is also valid (and would match, say both car and czar

Answer (score 0):

% is a wildcard and can replace an character, or combination of characters.  Use ? instead which replaces a single character.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like: (play with the numbers, I don't have pervasive to test with)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM BOM_SUB_LEVEL 
 where SUBSTRING(TOP_CODE, 11,1) = '-'
```